# Need Help for webservice

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I generate one simple Web services. In it, when i call services, output will be display differently. code is...

```
public class DistictName
{
       public string DisticName { get; set; }
}
public class Distict
{
    public string DistictName { get; set; }
    public List<DistictName> DistName { get; set; }
}        

[WebMethod]
public Distict DistictNameByState(String StateName)
{
    Distict DName = new Distict();
    DName.DistName = new List<DistictName>();
    DataTable dtDistictName = clsDefault.getproduct("sp_getDistictName", "Distict", StateName.ToString());

    for (int i = 0; i < dtDistictName.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        DName.DistName.Add(new DistictName() { DisticName = dtDistictName.Rows[i]["Distict_Name"].ToString() });
    }       
    return DName;
}
```

when I enter state name for example Gujarat and District name will be display on SoapUI editor like...

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <DistictNameByStateResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
         <DistictNameByStateResult>
            <DistName>
               <DistictName>
                  <DisticName>Ahmedabad</DisticName>
               </DistictName>
               <DistictName>
                  <DisticName>Amreli</DisticName>
               </DistictName>
               <DistictName>
                  <DisticName>Anand</DisticName>
               </DistictName>
               <DistictName>
                  <DisticName>Aravalli</DisticName>
               </DistictName>
               <DistictName>
                  <DisticName>Banaskantha</DisticName>
               </DistictName>
               <DistictName>
                  <DisticName>Bharuch</DisticName>
               </DistictName>
               <DistictName>
                  <DisticName>Bhavnagar</DisticName>
               </DistictName>               
            </DistName>
         </DistictNameByStateResult>
      </DistictNameByStateResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

But i need this type of output...

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
       <soap:Body>
          <DistictNameByStateResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
             <DistictNameByStateResult>
                <DistName>                   
                      <DisticName>Ahmedabad</DisticName>                  
                      <DisticName>Amreli</DisticName>                   
                      <DisticName>Anand</DisticName>                 
                      <DisticName>Aravalli</DisticName>                  
                      <DisticName>Banaskantha</DisticName>                  
                      <DisticName>Bharuch</DisticName>                  
                      <DisticName>Bhavnagar</DisticName>                              
                </DistName>
             </DistictNameByStateResult>
          </DistictNameByStateResponse>
       </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>
```

How to do it? what i can change in my Code...?

Comment: is this code working because what i can see here is that it should give an error as you are using property as type in line public List<DistictName> DistName { get; set; }

Comment: Once again i update my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return `List<Distict>`. So you need to use folloiwng code.

```
public class Distict
{
    public string DistictName { get; set; }
}        

[WebMethod]
public List<Distict> DistictNameByState(String StateName)
{
    List<Distict> DName = new List<Distict>();
    DataTable dtDistictName = clsDefault.getproduct("sp_getDistictName", "Distict", StateName.ToString());

    for (int i = 0; i < dtDistictName.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        Distict dst = new Distict();
        dst.DisticName = dtDistictName.Rows[i]["Distict_Name"].ToString() ;
        DName.Add(dst);
    }       
    return DName;
}
```

Comment: can property be used as type as above code is using property as type, just curious to now

Comment: this seems to be fine rest only the one who asked question can confirm it

Comment: i try but it will not working. The error display here...

1 'CountryServices.Distict' does not contain a definition for 'DisticName'

2 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<CountryServices.Distict>' to 'CountryServices.Distict'